# How to get notified whenever the URL in the address bar changes Firefox JPM

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is it possible to detect whether an URL changes, while developing Firefox addons using the new SDK/JPM?

It's not exactly hashchange what I want to detect, but any changes to the URL, like ajax request changing search terms or things like that.

Is it a way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: you could use an interval and check if the location changed compared to the previous check.

Comment: That's resource consuming. There should be a better way. Just like when you hook into the event "load" or something alike.

Comment: True, but how would you deal with arbitrary Javascript that manipulates the url without any load or other event?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. If there's an event being triggered when the URL changes (like the hashchange event) or if I can catch the javascript ajax requests somehow (Bare in mind they can't be catch with normal .ajaxComplete calls). I've been looking through MutationObservers, hooking them into DOM changes, but they don't seem to work all the time.

Comment: I think an interval function will be your best/only option to deal with all possible ways that can change the browser location. I wish you good luck to find an alternative. Btw I don't think that polling the url and comparing it with the previous result will affect performance that much as long as you keep the interval time decent (ie 50ms-100ms will be ok)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution which includes using a combination of [MutationObserver](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dfnReturnLink-1) and "old location value checking".

Basically I implemented a value check on `location.href` but using a `MutationObserver` to detect changes in the DOM, instead of using an interval which would kill the performance and waste some precious milliseconds.

Thanks for the contributions. Hope this helps anyone.